# PyGitHub: Unable to access private repositories of my team

Tags: python, github-api, pygithub

I want to access a private repository of a team that I am part of. However, I am not able to access it. It throws an exception as follows:

```
UnknownObjectException: 404 {u'documentation_url': u'https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-teams', u'message': u'Not Found'}
```

My code:

```
from github import Github
import pandas as pd


git = Github("token")
org = git.get_organization('org')

org.get_repo('repo_name')
```

It throws n error at the above statement.

I want to access this repository and get the count of number of teams who have access to the repository. However, I got the above mentioned error at the last line of the above code.

Can someone help me to fix this?

Comment: I guess both of it does the same thing if my understanding of what you said is correct. However, I tried what you said but didn't work :-(

Answer (score 4):

For future readers who are security-minded like me and want a read-only Personal Access Token, to read your private repos, you will need this enabled (and the OP will have to generate a new token).

[image: github PAT]

Comment: Nice catch, thanks. Helped me.

Answer (score 3):

**For Github Enterprise:**

```
from github import Github  

g = Github(base_url="https://your_host_name/api/v3", login_or_token="your_access_token") 
org = g.get_organization("your_org")  
repo = org.get_repo(repo_name)   # getting the repo 
print(repo)
```

**For Github :**

```
from github import Github  

g = Github(username,password)) 
repo = g.get_repo(repo_name)   # getting the repo 
print(repo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Which repo_name is used?

Example:  team_X/repo_1

If using github() directly:  `repo = github().get_repo("team_X/repo_1")`

If using org object to get repo: `repo = org.get_repo("repo_1")`